Storage conditions for Propidum Monoazide
I'm a junoir research assistant working on a mini project under my supervisor right now.
I was just wondering if anyone else has worked with Propidium monoazide (PMA) in water for PCR. Currently our protocol is to store our PMA solution at 4°C covered in the dark. However, after reading further literature I have seen PMA after dilution being stored at -20°C or lower, covered and in the dark. I was wondering if there would be any change to the solution between these two methods that would impact my future PCR assessment.
Regards and thank you for taking your time to read this.
